# work with sub folders of the file that the user was chosen

Tags: java, actionlistener, jfilechooser

i'm trying to let the user choose one file that contains also a couple of files (not fixed). in those folder there is file that i want to work on.

how can i do it?

```
public class MyActionLIstener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
        if(click.getSource() == btn){
            File directory;
            System.out.println("button clicked");
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                directory = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println(directory.getAbsolutePath());

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through all files in the directory.

```
// ...
directory = chooser.getSelectedFile();
File[] filesInDirectory = directory.listFiles(/* Optional filter */);
// ...
```

`filesInDirectory` contains all files in the directory. You can check if the files in the array are also directories or your desired file.